# Select a count of contacts from accounts using FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-webapi

Does anyone know the FetchXML format in order to select the count of contacts for accounts?

For example, I would have a list of AccountID's that I would us an IN filter for and I would just require the AccountID and the integer count of the contacts for that account.

Solved (see below) with a minor change to group by accounts.  Here is the final fetchxml that I used:

```
<fetch xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" aggregate="true" distinct="false" mapping="logical"> 
<entity name="contact">
<attribute name="contactid" alias="recordcount" aggregate="count" />
<link-entity name="account" to="accountid" alias="accountid">
<attribute name="accountid" alias="accountid" groupby="true" />
<filter>
<condition attribute="accountid" operator="in">
<value>708039fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
<value>0a8139fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
<value>428139fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
<value>4a8139fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
<value>618139fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
<value>9f8139fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
<value>ae8239fd-f7b1-e811-a973-000d3af4a510</value>
</condition>
</filter>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an aggregate fetch with a group by on the parentcustomerid.

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='contact'> 
        <attribute name='contactid' alias='contact_count' aggregate='countcolumn' /> 
        <attribute name='parentcustomerid' alias='parentcustomerid' groupby='true' />
        <link-entity name='account' from='accountid' to='parentcustomerid'>
            <filter type='and'>
                <condition attribute='accountid' operator='in'>
                    <value>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}</value>
                    <value>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}</value>
                </condition >
            </filter>
        </link-entity> 
    </entity> 
</fetch>
```

Comment: This would give you the total number of contacts for all listed accounts, not **per** account

Comment: @jasonscript The filter on the account link-entity will restrict the contacts to the listed accounts.  The parentcustomerid with groupby = true will result in one row per listed account with a contact count specific to that account.

Comment: Using the linked entity worked and I just had to move the groupby to the account object so that it would give me unique AccountId's with the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward when you [use Rollup field](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/passiondynamics/archive/2018/04/24/count-the-number-related-child-records-using-a-rollup-field).

Then you can query the count easily.

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="name"  />
    <attribute name="new_contactcountrollup"  />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Update:

Why I said subquery is not supported in fetchxml since I was thinking the second solution.

```
--using just JOIN
SELECT a.accountid, count(1) AS [contact count] FROM contact c
INNER JOIN account a
ON c.parentcustomerid = a.accountid
WHERE a.accountid IN  (
'{0ACDC4F5-4885-E811-A967-000D3A1A9407}', '{BA41CEBA-199F-E811-A96B-000D3A1A9EFB}')
GROUP BY a.accountid

--using SUBQUERY
SELECT a.accountid,
    (SELECT Count(1) FROM contact c WHERE c.parentcustomerid = a.accountid) AS [contact count]
    FROM account a
    WHERE a.accountid IN (
'{0ACDC4F5-4885-E811-A967-000D3A1A9407}', '{BA41CEBA-199F-E811-A96B-000D3A1A9EFB}')
```

Comment: It does not have to be a subquery, the answer above with aggregate, groupby and count works fine :)

Comment: @JonasRapp I know, but opinion differs. CRM OOB rollup field is my answer.

Comment: Absolutely :)
Comment was to the subquery statement, which I now see you edited :)

Comment: @JonasRapp I was thinking about second solution - see my update :)

Comment: Yep, I figured so. But even in SQL that is a messy way of simply counting contacts by account ;) Group By would be better there too. In my opinion.... :)